# Use Open CV Python to create dispairty map with StereoBM with diagonal parallax

Tags: python, opencv, parallax, stereoscopy

I have a stereo pair and would like to create a disparity map. However, the shift between the two images in not simply left to right or up and down, but some combination of the two. I have tried to use the StereoBM function in Open CV Python but the results have diagonal black and white lines across the image. My question is, is it possible to use two images where the parallax is in the diagonal direction to compute a disparity map, or do the images need to be rotated in order for this function to work?

EDIT: After reading the answers below, and doing some research, I decided to try the stereoRectifyUncalibrated function. I first find key points in the first image with SURF, and then repeat this for the second image. I then use the FLANN based matcher to match the points, and I remove the outliers. I then find the fundamental mat using the findFundamentalMat function, and then I call stereoRectifyUncalibrated. However, I get an error that begins like this: (-215) CV_IS_MAT(_points1) && CV_IS_MAT(_points2) && (_points1->rows == 1 || _points1->cols == 1) &&...

I have made sure that the data types of everything are the same, and that each point array are the same dimensions. I put the part of my code where I use stereoRectifyUncalibrated below.

```
#Detect feature points with SURF
detector = cv2.SURF()
kp1, desc1 = detector.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, desc2 = detector.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

#Match Points
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1  # bug: flann enums are missing
flann_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(flann_params, {})
matches = matcher.knnMatch(desc1, trainDescriptors = desc2, k=2)
mkp1, mkp2 = [], []
ratio = 0.75
for m in matches:
    if len(m) == 2 and m[0].distance < m[1].distance * ratio:
        m = m[0]
        mkp1.append( kp1[m.queryIdx] )
        mkp2.append( kp2[m.trainIdx] )
np.float32([kp.pt for kp in mkp1])
p1 = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in mkp1])
p2 = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in mkp2])
kp_pairs = zip(mkp1, mkp2)
H, status = cv2.findHomography(p1, p2, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
print '%d / %d  inliers/matched' % (np.sum(status), len(status))
statusmat = np.zeros((max(status.shape),2),dtype = np.float64)
statusmat[:,0] = status[:,0]
statusmat[:,1] = status[:,0]
status = np.array(status, dtype=bool)
p1f=p1[status.view(np.ndarray).ravel()==1,:] #Remove Outliers
p2f=p2[status.view(np.ndarray).ravel()==1,:] #Remove Outliers

#Attempt to rectify using stereoRectifyUncalibrated
fundmat, mask = cv2.findFundamentalMat(p1f,p2f,cv2.RANSAC,3,0.99,)
rectmat1, rectmat2 = cv2.stereoRectifyUncalibrated(p1f,p2f,fundmat,imgsize)
```

Thanks for the answers so far!

Comment: Did you perform image stereo rectification (using `stereoRectify` ([doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectify)) or `stereoRectifyUncalibrated` ([doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectifyuncalibrated))) before using StereoBM ?

Comment: Hello, I tried using the stereoRectifyUncalibrated method. I can not calibrate them using the checkerboard pattern. I have created the fundamental matrix using feature points generated by SURF and matched with the FLANN matcher. However, when I try to run the stereoRectifyUncalibrated function, I get a long error that begins like this: (-215) CV_IS_MAT(_points1) && CV_IS_MAT(_points2) && (_points1->rows == 1 || _points1->cols == 1) &&....  
I read that this may be a bug where the function does not accept the funamental matrix, but I can not find a solution for it.

Comment: This error seems to be related with the point arrays you are giving to the function, not the fundamental matrix. It shows the assertion that should be true but was found to be false. Could you edit your question and show how you do the call to `stereoRectifyUncalibrated`?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this function stereoRectifyUncalibrated takes a row or column vector, not a n x 2 matrix
Also output seems to have 3 elements

```
p1fNew = p1f.reshape((p1f.shape[0] * 2, 1))
p2fNew = p2f.reshape((p2f.shape[0] * 2, 1))

retBool ,rectmat1, rectmat2 = cv2.stereoRectifyUncalibrated(p1fNew,p2fNew,fundmat,imgsize)
```